# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.x

Командная строка ругается на этот код. Почему? Что не так с ним?

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs, sys
outf = codecs.getwriter('cp866') (sys.stdout, errors='replace')
sys.stdout = outf

from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "Я собираюсь стереть файл %r" % filename
print "Если вы не хотите стирать его, нажмите сочетание клавиш CTRL+C (^C)."
print "Если хотите стереть файл, нажмите клавижу Enter."
```

Выдает

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex16.py", line 11, in <module>
    print "Я собираюсь стереть файл %r" % filename
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 357, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp866.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Объясните, что делать или что-то не так пишу?

Comment: Вы пихаете в `outf` байтовую строку, но он не знает что с ней делать, пытается декодировать стандартной кодировкой `ascii` и обламывается

Comment: @andreymal , тогда, что нужно писать вместо него?

Comment: @andreymal, понял свою ошибку. Спасибо за помощь! Нужно просто было убрать outf = ... и sys.stdout = outf